# Stroke() with pressure

Tags: processing, stroke

In Processing there are 3 strokeCap() modes: SQUARE, PROJECT, or ROUND. However, I am trying to get an effect whereby the stroke simulates pressure like in Photoshop.

[image]

Is there any way I can get an effect like this by programming it out? I am thinking of using ellipse that increase and decrease in size gradually but I am stuck in having determining where the stroke start and end when drawing the sketch.

Comment: You've mentioned an approach. What happened when you tried that approach? Where is your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? You might also want to check out the Handy library: http://www.gicentre.net/handy/

Answer (score 1):

This might be a very rudimentary approach to what you want, but could be a good starting point. I am not sure if you want a full-feature for pressure-sensitivity, but this solution is something that imitates that effect, by replacing pressure with speed. It's an example from "*Learning Processing*", by Daniel Shiffman. Here's a link to the code: http://learningprocessing.com/exercises/chp03/exercise-03-07-absolute-value

I'll also post it here.

```
// Learning Processing
// Daniel Shiffman
// http://www.learningprocessing.com

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
  background(255);
  smooth();
}

void draw() {
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(abs(pmouseX - mouseX));
  line(pmouseX, pmouseY, mouseX, mouseY);
}
```

Hope this is a good starting point to what you need.